# iphone: initialize part of a nib file multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

I design my `UITableView` by Interface Builder.

I can use a separate nib file for `UITableViewCell`, but not so convenient for me.

So, I want to have my custom `UITableViewCell` in the same nib file 
(another object in the same level with UITableView's object)

Do you know how to initialize custom `UITableViewCell` object many times, efficiently way?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184206/loading-custom-table-view-cells-from-nib-files..see this post that may be help you..

Comment: thanks, now I'm questioning about: how to copy a UITableViewCell?

Comment: UIViews do not support NSCopying

Comment: anyway to unarchive part of a nib file?

Comment: There is no such a thing as a partly loaded NIB. I don't know your reasons but moving the cell UI to a separate NIB is highly recommended, or, if you don't want to mess with Interface Builder, build the cell entirely from code. Ah, and don't forget to set the reuseIdentifier for optimal performance.

Comment: Thanks Lvsti. My reason is I want to group related nibs together, and don't want to create many files. After a while, I do use a separate nib, but still want to know an answer for this :)